# How to import unstructured Excel file into SQL Server (for example with SSIS)?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, import-from-excel

I want to periodically import Excel files into SQL Server. My problem is that every time I want to import the Excel files, it looks different.

For example, see the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of example Excel-file]

As you can see, there are three blocks I want to import. But, the problem is, that the first row/cell of block C, always starts on a different rownumber because the number of rows of block B could vary.

What is the best solution to import this Excel file periodically?

I already tried some things with SSIS, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Arrange you block such that there is only 1 block per worksheet.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your answer Alex. Unfortunately there will be a few hundred Excel files per time. So, it's not possible / efficient to alter the Excel files manually.

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? How do you envisage the import function will recognise different blocks?